# C++: Iteration of the map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I couldn't find any solution for my problem. Let's assume that we've got n elements of such map:

```
std::map<string, string> tmpMap;
```

We've also got iterator to this map:

```
std::map<string, string>::iterator itTmpMap = tmpMap.begin();
```

How can I now change iterator to for example fourth pair? Compilator doesn't let me just add an integer to iterator.

```
Compilator error: 
int a = 4;
itTmpMap = itTmpMap + a;
```

Comment: [`std::advance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Comment: You couldn't find a solution? There are so many duplicates :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function `std::advance()`. It takes a reference, rather than returning a new iterator, an oddity which I've never understood...

Comment: C++11 has `std::next` and `std::prev` if you prefer to work off the return value.

Comment: It's not really an "oddity"; it avoids a copy while fitting into the common use cases. C++ doesn't give you what you don't need. Well, it didn't used to anyway :D

Comment: @LRO, AFAIK (and my knowledge is not extensive), this is the only function that takes an iterator by reference(?)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::advance(itTmpMap, 4);` The map iterator is a *bidirectional* iterator, not a *random-access* iterator.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` has a bidirectional iterator. Operation iterator + integral type is not defined for bidirectional iterators. So to get the equivalemt iterator of itTmpMap + 4 you have 4 times to increase it. 
The C++ Standard defines special functions for such an operation. You can use either `std::advance` that has return type void. For example

```
std::advance( itTmpMap, 4 );
```

Or you can use `std::next`that return reference to the source incremented iterator. For example

```
std::next( itTmpMap, 4 );
```

For example to traverse the map starting with the fourth iterator you could write

```
std::for_each( std::next( tmpMap.begin(), 4 ), tmpMap.end(), SomeFunction );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the iterator 4 times:

```
++itTmpMap;
++itTmpMap;
++itTmpMap;
++itTmpMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterators for `std::map` are bidirectional.  There are several operations that are valid for such iterators, but adding an integer to move it is not one of them.  There are a couple ways you can do this:

```
// this will advance the iterator 4 times
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    itTmpMap++;
```

Or, the preferred method

```
std::advance(itTmpMap, 4);
```